# Angularjs Protractor set window size bigger than screen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I'm using Protractor to do some e2e testing with an ng-grid, and I can't see all of the columns on my screen. I would like to make the window wider than the screen, so everything is shows in the window and there is no need to scroll.

I tried the following, but it doesn't make the window any bigger than my screen.

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setPosition(0, 0);
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(2000, 3000);
```

Any ideas on how I could force it to be bigger? Thanks!

Comment: What OS you're using? Mac?

Comment: I mostly test on Ubuntu, but it'd be nice to know how to do it for Ubuntu and Mac.

Comment: OK, i answered below for Ubuntu, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it using [setSize](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html#setSize%28org.openqa.selenium.Dimension%29) in the same way you can't do it with [window.resizeTo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp).

Alternatives are OS specific:

#### Linux:

Need to enable virtual screen resolutions, e.g.

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768 --fb 2000x3000 --panning 2000x3000
```

Where 1366x768 is the real display resolution of your physical display.
And 2000x3000 is the virtual resolution you want to achieve.

#### Windows:

Need to enable Remote Desktop Connections on windows machine.

And need to connect by setting up a custom resolution, for example from linux command line:

```
export MACHINE_IP=10.0.2.15
export WIN_USER_NAME=brendan
export WIN_USER_PWD=secret

rdesktop ${MACHINE_IP} -u ${WIN_USER_NAME} -p ${WIN_USER_PWD} -x b -a 16bpp -g "2000x3000" -r sound:off
```

#### Mac:

idk if exists. feel free to edit and add one